# jquery jsonp not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/project?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log("success");
});
});
```

Why this code is not working? Its not giving error also in browser. But a project file is being downloaded as script in Chrome as shown by Inspect Element tool. How can I get data from the file?

Comment: Please don't tell us that you're getting an error without also telling us what the error is. We're not mind-readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Atlassian use `jsonp-callback` instead of `callback` as the parameter in a query string for JSONP callbacks.

[See here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/REST/Atlassian+REST+API+Design+Guidelines+version+1).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you configure your JSONP-call with the [jQuery.ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/project",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsonp-callback",
    data: { /* additional parameters go here */ }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log("success");
  });
});
```

The option `jsonp` renames the JSONP-callback parameter as @mccannf suggested from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for future reference, you might consider using the jqXHR object to add error-handling functionality, so you can tell if the JSON request is failing. See jQuery's reference (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jq = $.getJSON('https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/project?callback=?',
              function(data) {
                console.log("success");
              })
    .error(function() { console.log("error occurred"); });
});
```